# How to resolve Error Interface "Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia" not found

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-medialibrary

I have installed Spatie Media Library in a Laravel 9 project. Following the document, I have set my `User` model to implement `HasMedia` and also use `InteractsWithMedia` like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Spatie\Image\Manipulations;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements HasMedia
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, InteractsWithMedia;

    // ...
}
```

I have also been able to upload images locally in my user controller like this

```
if ($request->has('photo')) {
    $user->addMedia($request->photo)
        ->toMediaCollection('user-photos');
}
```

After deploying to my staging server, I am getting this error

> local.ERROR: Interface "Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia" not found {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Interface "Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia" not found at .../app/Models/User.php:15)

I ran `composer dump-autoload` on the server and that has not fixed the error. Why am I getting this error and what possible solutions can I use for resolving this error?

Comment: Did you run `composer update` on the staging server?

Comment: Try running `composer install` again to check for any errors

Comment: Please share more details. How did you deploy your application? Did you check whether the class that is missing is present on your server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by running these commands `php artisan config:cache` and `php artisan queue:restart`.

Turned out that the reason for the error was because queue worker was still using the previously cached environment variables. Both commands ensured the newly set disk in environment file was now available to the queue worker.

Answer (score 1):

Did `composer update` and `php artisan cache:clear` but still got the error `Undefined type 'Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia'`.
Closing VSCode v1.78.2 and opening it resolved the error message.

Comment: I also closed and opened vscode and the error disappeared. Very strange but thanks

Answer (score -1):

Change this

```
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
```

To

```
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia\HasMedia;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it